# Coloring Cells(Cell values contains decimal percentage) based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on one of the enhancement in macros , where i have to change the 
cell font color based on value:
If greater than 5 then "RED"
If less than 1 then "AMBER"

Cell contains below values:

```
CB
0.30%
3.00%
3.00%
2.00%
2.00%
2.00%
3.00%
0.00%
0.00%
6.00%
0.00%
70.00%
70.00%
45.00%
```

**Code:**

```
Dim My_Range As Range
Set My_Range = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schemes").Range("CB15:CB100")

    Dim BValue As String
    'Dim AValue_1 As String
    'Dim AValue_2 As Integer
    'Dim AValue_3 As Integer

    For Each Cell In My_Range
        BValue = Cell.Value
        'AValue_1 = CStr(Left(BValue, Len(BValue) - 1))
        'AValue_2 = InStr(1, AValue_1, ".")
        'AValue_3 = Left(AValue_1, AValue_2 - 1)
        'AValue_3 = AValue_2(0)


        If BValue > 5 Then
            Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 0
            Cell.Font.Bold = True
        Else
            Cell.Font.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If

        If BValue < 1 Then
            Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 44
            Cell.Font.Bold = True
        Else
            Cell.Font.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If

    Next
```

Not getting appropriate result as cell contains fractional percent values.Could you guys please guide me.

Comment: You could just use **Conditional Formatting**, either set it up manually or in code.

Answer (score 0):

Percentage values are less than one: 5% = 0.05 and 100% = 1 - so try it like this instead

```
Dim My_Range As Range
Set My_Range = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schemes").Range("CB15:CB100")

For Each Cell In My_Range
    Select Case Cell.Value
        Case Is > 0.05
            Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 0 ' should be RED, but 0 is BLACK
            Cell.Font.Bold = True
        Case Is < 0.01
            Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 44 ' AMBER
            Cell.Font.Bold = True
        Case Else
            Cell.Font.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Thanks braX for your quick response. AMBER condition working fine. RED is working fine but it is making RED for the cells with percentage value >1 and <5. 2.00% RED
2.00% RED
2.00% RED
0.00% AMBER
0.00% AMBER
0.00% AMBER
0.00% AMBER
0.70% AMBER
0.30% AMBER
0.30% AMBER
0.30% AMBER
0.30% AMBER
0.30% AMBER
0.30% AMBER
0.30% AMBER
0.30% AMBER
3.00% RED
3.00% RED
3.00% RED
I think we should add another condition like Case Is > 0.01 AND Is < 0.05. Plz suggest.

Comment: I dont really understand your comment, but you can see how using a `Select Case` has its advantages. just program for each case, and keep in mind you can use multiple conditions in a `Case` statement if you need to define a range instead of something just being greater than OR less than something.

Comment: Case Is > 0.05
            Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 0 ' should be RED, but 0 is BLACK
            Cell.Font.Bold = True   . Above condition is making RED for all cells with percentage >1 instead of >5. So seeking for some conditions to satisfies for cells with value >1 and <5 to keep the cells unchanged.

Comment: braX...My condition is  1. <1 ----AMBER                                                                
                                    2. >1 and <5 -----No Change                                           
                                    3. >5 -----Red.                                                                              your condition ... 1. <1 ----Is working fine                                                                               
 2. >1 and <5 -----Is making RED                                        
 3. >5 -----Is making BLACK

Comment: braX...below is the final code which is working as per my requirement.                  
Dim My_Range As Range
Set My_Range = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schemes").Range("CB15:CB100")
For Each Cell In My_Range
Select Case Cell.Value
    Case Is > 0.05
        Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 'should be RED
        Cell.Font.Bold = True
    Case Is < 0.01
        Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 44 ' AMBER
        Cell.Font.Bold = True
    Case Is > 0.01, Is < 0.05
        Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 0 ' No Change
    Case Else
        Cell.Font.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Select
Next.  Thanks for all support.

Comment: You can add it as your own answer and mark that one as the accepted answer instead of posting it in a comment... as you can see putting long code in comments just creates a mess.